# Passing validated_data with source attribute on field back into nested serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

**Scenario:** I have a serializer containing a nested serializer and I want to use the *create* function on that nested serializer in order to keep my business logic in one place.

**Problem:** Because the nested serializer uses the *source* attribute for a field, the `validated_data` on the parent serializer contains the model field as opposed to the serializer field name. When I go to pass this back in, it fails validation

Example:

```
class FooSerializer():
    foo_amount = serializers.IntegerField(source='foo_quantity')

    class Meta:
        class = Foo
        fields = ('foo_amount')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Some business logic

class BarSerializer():
    foo = FooSerializer()

    class Meta:
        class = Bar
        fields = ('foo')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        foo_serializer = FooSerializer(validated_data.pop('foo'))
        
        # Always going to fail because validated_data has 'foo_quantity' as a key
        if foo_serializer.is_valid():
            foo = foo_serializer.save()
```

Comment: This looks a bit weird to me. You are saying that you expect `foo_amount` but sending `food_quantity`. Why not send `food_amount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way to solve this issue, but I found that I could use `initial_data` as my data source for the validator.

So going off the example above, my solution was:

```
class BarSerializer():
    foo = FooSerializer()

    class Meta:
        class = Bar
        fields = ('foo')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        foo_serializer = FooSerializer(initial_data.get('foo'))
        
        if foo_serializer.is_valid():
            foo = foo_serializer.save()
```